# Why is a DOM Object Dependent on Internet an Explorer Application in VBA

Tags: vba, dom, excel

So I have an internet explorer object, and I'm using it to get a DOM object after navigating to a page.  (Actually, I'm getting a collection of DOM Form Objects, but I'm trying to keep the question as generic as possible.)

```
Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")
ie.navigate (URL)
Set DOM = ie.document
```

Then i want to quit ie a la `ie.quit`, and continue working with my new DOM object. Unfortunately, quitting ie seems to empty out the dom object of all it's contents.  Is there a way to stop this from happening?  I really don't want to leave ie open until the end of the program as it a) is a resource hog, and b) tends to lead to a lot of unclosed instances in the event of errors further down the line.  Thanks, and sorry if the answer turns out to be really  obvious (which it feels like it might be, although I REALLY did hunt around.)

Comment: If you can use GET and/or POST requests to return the data you need then try using an `XMLHTTP60` object instead - documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms759148%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you can quit IE at the point where you are holding the object. Unless I'm missing something, you're holding a reference to a COM object; the COM object isn't stored in your application but managed by IE, so when throw away IE, you throw away your object with it.

I would attempt to hold onto the DOM for the shortest time possible if you are concerned about resource utilization, but if you need access to the DOM, you need to keep IE around.

If you only need parts of the data, you can of course always pull out the relevant bits from the DOM, get rid of IE and work on the data you just pulled out.

Comment: How would I go about pulling out the important parts?  I've tried doing a getElementsByTagName, but the objects created by that get thrown out with ie just the same

Comment: You'll have to pull out the elements you need and store them in native VBA variables, not objects that you request from the DOM, as those are stored in the IE Application object also.

Answer (score 1):

The DOM lives in the Internet Explorer process address space, which is separate from your application. What your have on your side is just in-process proxies objects for external out-of-process DOM objects. By doing `ie.quit` you effectively terminate the IE process and cut off its DOM.

It is also not clear from your code if you wait for `DocumentComplete` event before accessing the DOM. You certainly can't access it right away after calling `Navigate`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.  So is there ABSOLUTELY NO way to import the DOM in its entirety? I guess I could do an HTTP get on the page create my own, but is seems like there must be an easier way...

Comment: You could probably try replicating a snapshot of the current DOM state as XML Document in your VBA, but that would be quite tedious. Another option might be to host WebBrowser control in-process, but I am not sure if that's possible with VBA. Plus, the memory overhead would still be noticeable.